# TypeError: string indices must be integers - check_dell_warrant.py

Tags: python, nagios

I am using a plugin developed for Nagios but I am getting an error when running on certain hosts. I would normally debug but am very new to python programming. The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_dell_warranty.py", line 755, in <module>
  parse_exit(RESULT, options.short_output)
 File "/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_dell_warranty.py", line 589, in parse_exit
  days, short_output)
File "/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_dell_warranty.py", line 557, in process_asset
days, short_output)
File "/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_dell_warranty.py", line 497, in build_warranty_line
 description = warranty['ServiceLevelDescription']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The code from the script shows:

```
def build_warranty_line(warranty, full_line, days, short_output):
'''
This function takes a warranty object and parses the salient information
out. It then calculates the number of days remaining in the warranty
period, and builds a line for Nagios outputting.
'''

description = warranty['ServiceLevelDescription']
end_date = warranty['EndDate']
start_date = warranty['StartDate']
provider = warranty['ServiceProvider']

logger.debug('Found: Start date: {0}, End Date: {1},Description: {2}, '
             'Provider: {3}'.format(start_date, end_date, description,
                                    provider))
```

If I run the script in debug mode it shows the raw data which is passed to this function is:

```
DEBUG - Attempting to load libsmbios_c.
DEBUG - Unable to load libsmbios_c continuing.
DEBUG - Obtaining serial number via OpenManage.
DEBUG - Requesting service tags: GSF0YX1
DEBUG - Requesting warranty information from Dell url:            
https://api.dell.com/support/v2/assetinfo/warranty/tags.json?      
apikey=1adecee8a60444738f280aad1cd87d0e&svctags=GSF0YX1
DEBUG - Raw output received:
 {u'GetAssetWarrantyResponse': {u'@xmlns': u'http://tempuri.org/',      u'GetAssetWarrantyResult': {u'Faults': None, u'@a': u'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dell.AWR.Domain.Asset', u'@i': u'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', u'Response': {u'DellAsset': {u'MachineDescription': u'PowerEdge R720', u'ShipDate': u'2013-05-08T00:00:00', u'ServiceTag': u'GSF0YX1', u'OrderNumber': 68701126, u'LocalChannel': u'IRL', u'AssetParts': {u'@nil': u'true'}, u'CountryLookupCode': 808, u'ItemClassCode': u'TE002', u'IsDuplicate':  u'false', u'ParentServiceTag': {u'@nil': u'true'}, u'CustomerNumber': 5503647,  u'Warranties': {u'Warranty': {u'StartDate': u'2013-05-08T00:00:00', u'EndDate': u'2016-05- 08T23:59:59', u'ServiceProvider': {u'@nil': u'true'}, u'ServiceLevelCode': u'ND', u'ItemNumber': u'709-11115', u'EntitlementType': u'INITIAL', u'ServiceLevelDescription': u'Next Business Day', u'ServiceLevelGroup': 99999}}}}}}}
DEBUG - Testing for faults in json response.
DEBUG - Raw fault return: None
DEBUG - No faults found.
DEBUG - Beginning to parse results and construct exit line and code.
DEBUG - Assets obtained: {u'MachineDescription': u'PowerEdge R720', u'ShipDate': u'2013-05-08T00:00:00', u'ServiceTag': u'GSF0YX1', u'OrderNumber': 68701126, u'LocalChannel': u'IRL', u'AssetParts': {u'@nil': u'true'}, u'CountryLookupCode': 808, u'ItemClassCode': u'TE002', u'IsDuplicate': u'false', u'ParentServiceTag': {u'@nil': u'true'}, u'CustomerNumber': 5503647, u'Warranties': {u'Warranty': {u'StartDate': u'2013-05-08T00:00:00', u'EndDate': u'2016-05-08T23:59:59', u'ServiceProvider': {u'@nil': u'true'}, u'ServiceLevelCode': u'ND', u'ItemNumber': u'709-11115', u'EntitlementType': u'INITIAL', u'ServiceLevelDescription': u'Next Business Day', u'ServiceLevelGroup': 99999}}}
DEBUG - A single asset is being processed.
DEBUG - Raw asset being processed: {u'MachineDescription': u'PowerEdge R720', u'ShipDate': u'2013-05-08T00:00:00', u'ServiceTag': u'GSF0YX1', u'OrderNumber': 68701126, u'LocalChannel': u'IRL', u'AssetParts': {u'@nil': u'true'}, u'CountryLookupCode': 808, u'ItemClassCode': u'TE002', u'IsDuplicate': u'false', u'ParentServiceTag': {u'@nil': u'true'}, u'CustomerNumber': 5503647, u'Warranties': {u'Warranty': {u'StartDate': u'2013-05-08T00:00:00', u'EndDate': u'2016-05-08T23:59:59', u'ServiceProvider': {u'@nil': u'true'}, u'ServiceLevelCode': u'ND', u'ItemNumber': u'709-11115', u'EntitlementType': u'INITIAL', u'ServiceLevelDescription': u'Next Business Day', u'ServiceLevelGroup': 99999}}}
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to show us the actual call to `build_warranty_line`, but your error means that `warranty` is a string, not a dict. Did you `json.loads` the JSON response?

Comment: I didn't actually write the script myself but the version I am using is online here: [link](https://gitorious.org/smarmy/check_dell_warranty/source/b6438fbef45ba22be3bf0aa2e0aa2e444a384813:check_dell_warranty.py)